# データクラスのインスタンス生成時に警告メッセージを出したい

Tags: python

## やりたいこと

データクラスを使用した際、非推奨である旨を警告メッセージとして出力したいです。
具体的には、データクラスのインスタンスを生成したときにメッセージを出力したいです。

## 試したこと

データクラス`Human`の`__init__`メソッドに、警告メッセージを出力する処理を追加したいです。
以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
import warnings
from functools import wraps
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass

def _process_class(cls, deprecated_date: str, new_class_name: Optional[str] = None):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            message = f"deprecated: {deprecated_date}以降に廃止します。"
            if new_class_name is not None:
                message += f"替わりに'{new_class_name}'を使用してください。"
            warnings.warn(
                message,
                DeprecationWarning,
            )

        return wrapped

    cls.__init__ = decorator(cls.__init__)  # type: ignore
    return cls


def deprecated_class(_cls=None, *, deprecated_date: str, new_class_name: Optional[str] = None):
    """クラスを非推奨にします。"""

    def wrap(cls):
        return _process_class(cls, deprecated_date=deprecated_date, new_class_name=new_class_name)

    if _cls is None:
        return wrap
    return wrap(_cls)


@deprecated_class(deprecated_date="2021-09-01")
@dataclass
class Human:
    """非推奨なクラス"""
    name:str
    age:int
```

しかし`Human`クラスのインスタンスを生成しようとすると、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Human("alice",18)
```

```
...
/usr/lib/python3.8/dataclasses.py in wrapper(self)
    366         repr_running.add(key)
    367         try:
--> 368             result = user_function(self)
    369         finally:
    370             repr_running.discard(key)

/usr/lib/python3.8/dataclasses.py in __repr__(self)

AttributeError: 'Human' object has no attribute 'name'
```

## 質問

エラーの原因は何で、どうすれば解決できるでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、`OldHuman`は`Human`の間違いです。訂正しました。

Comment: python 3.8.6/3.9.5 で動作を確認したのですが、きちんと `DeprecationWarning` が表示されます。例えば、`Human(name="alice", age=18)` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: `Human(name="alice", age=18)`でも結果は同じで、エラーが発生しました。Python3.8.6環境です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrapperd`関数に`function(*args, **kwargs)`が必要でした。

`wrapped`関数を以下の通り書き換えたら、期待通りの動きになりました。

```
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            message = f"deprecated: {deprecated_date}以降に廃止します。"
            if new_class_name is not None:
                message += f"替わりに'{new_class_name}'を使用してください。"
            warnings.warn(
                message,
                DeprecationWarning,
            )
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
```